# Learning (& teaching) assembly with WASM (WebAssembly)?

Tags: javascript, webassembly

Given that [WASM](http://webassembly.org) reached [MVP](http://webassembly.org/roadmap/) in [February](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webassembly/2017Feb/0002.html), has anyone spent any time trying to work through the viability of using WASM to actually learn / teach higher level aspects of assembly with WebAssembly?

After going through a bit of material, it seems that it's still aimed at C/C++ development (perhaps due to the potential state of flux that still exists?) and there is no real material that talks about using WASM directly as far as learning assembly programming principles.

WASM is (at least could be) uniquely suited to learning, and teaching, assembly itself in a very universal manner that could later be extended to specific hardware, if desired. Learning WASM itself could be valuable for the general effort going forward and writing interesting and uniquely optimized programs.

It might even be neat to see interest in things like the old demo scene resurrected with WASM...

Comment: As an old demo scener I find hard to follow anything what puts "assembly" into name, and then starts its characteristic by "portable". That's not how machine code works and that's not how we put machines at the bleeding edge back when the power was limited. Now with unlimited power it's hard to justify not using some high level portable language like C++ and shaders.

Comment: The product  seems to be misnamed, much like JavaScript has little to do with Java. We also have .NET-assembly which isn't an assembly language at all.

Comment: BTW, for educational purposes with a goal to show low-level machinery, with direct connection to electronics/logical gates, I suggest to use something like: [Simple 8-bit Assembler simulator (web app)](http://schweigi.github.io/assembler-simulator/). This covers all very-basic principles, and is simple enough. I think it's missing a tiny adjustments to be perfect, but that can be covered by the lector+theory, if enough lessons are put into it (I think this can easily cover 6 or even 12 month span, if the students already know JS, they can even get advanced tasks to extend the simulator later).

Comment: I think we should all note that this is potentially quite a valuable question. It's quite likely that in the (not too distant) future, wasm will be used for compiler research and compiler education as it will most definitely be used for compiler creation in order to port languages to the "web" platform. In addition, even though wasm is certainly not like other assemblies due to its high-level nature, it is still also likely to be used for assembly education since it will be a highly targeted platform and will become a viable teaching point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Wasm is ideal for learning first things about assembly language. While it distills many of the basic operations available in modern CPUs, it also is a somewhat more high-level abstraction. For example:

- It is a stack machine.
- It has an infinite set of virtual registers.
- It has structured control flow.
- It provides no access to the stack.
- It provides no access to code.
- It is typed.
- It will probably gain other more high-level features in the future.

Many of these are prerequisites to making Wasm *safe* and *portable*, which in itself is very unlike ordinary assembly languages.

(I happen to agree with those who say that "WebAssembly" is a bit of a misnomer -- both the "Web" part and the "Assembly" part, actually. It was a play on JavaScript previously being called "the assembly language of the web" for its ubiquity.)

Comment: The ∞ registers and lack of stack are great for teaching though: one *can* artificially constrain themselves to using 8 or 32 locals, and spill everything to the memory as if it were a stack. You can even "pin" a local as the stack pointer. Totally agree on the other points!

Answer (score 1):

WASM is just like regular processor assembly, but... for web :-) The same way 99.9% of people don't need to learn assembly if they don't want to, one doesn't need to learn WASM.

WASM will be very useful if you wanna jump into low level stuff and especially if you will deal with compilers. WASM will be a convenient way for someone to port, for example, the backend of a C++ compiler to work in the browser. So the same GCC/LLVM you compile to x86/x64/ARM/etc, will be able to compile for web as well.

Notice that besides the name Web "assembly", this has not too much to do with CPU architeture like x86 or x64. So "learning assembly with WASM" doesn't need one will be learning the "bare metal". Sometimes can be a little confusing.